# Unexpected token ( in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use this code to change color of every `.hdva` element, `if(some condition)`. I get `Unexpected token (` in Chrome console. (http://www.alera.cz, l: 2678)

```
$('.hdva').each(function() {
     var color = $(this).css('color');
     if ($(this).css.('color') === '#00ffff')
     {
         $(this).css.('color') === '#006699';
     }
 });
```

Can't see mistake in there, or is there something wrong?

Comment: Typo: There are extra `.` between `css` and its calling parenthesis in the 2nd and 3rd use. They should match the 1st.

Comment: Once you've set `color` in the var statement why are you re-evaluating `$(this).css('color')` in the if statement? The if statement could read `if (color === '#00ffff')`. Also beloe Ragnar supplied the correct syntax for the setting line inside the if statement.

Comment: good point, thank you. Although, function doesnt work, have to figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.` before `('color')`, the second line is not necessary, unless you need a color value for other purpose.

```
$('.hdva').each(function() {    
 if ($(this).css('color') == '#00ffff')
 {
     $(this).css('color', '#006699'); //use this way for setting the color instead of $(this).css.('color') === '#006699'; because it's a comparison, not an assignment.
 }
});
```

Another version using `var` in order to avoid two calls of `$(this)`

```
$('.hdva').each(function() {    
 var item = $(this);
 if (item.css('color') == '#00ffff')
 {
     item.css('color', '#006699');
 }
});
```

Comment: oh, thanks, I swear to god i was looking to that like half of hour :)) thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a dot you shouldn't have here : `css.('color')`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a dot after css:

```
.css.('color')
//  ^^
```

Remove them from your code.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line of your if statement and in the braces of the if statement, you have an extra '.' That will solve your syntax issue.